# Converting WMS to SHP?

Tags: python, wms, convert

I'm looking for tool that will be convert  WMS to vector layer.

Are they ready tool?(for example in python)

Comment: The WMS service usually gives outputs as an Image, and hence it is not possible to get the output as a Shapefile. If your server also has a WFS output, then we can get the vectors out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to perform Raster To Vector Conversion and some software options for that are compared in **[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster_to_vector_conversion_software)**.  The preceding step will be to copy the WMS into a raster data format (crudest would be a screenshot) and the subsequent step will be to create a map layer from the output vector data format (shapefile in your case).