# Automatically vectorizing data from WMS using ArcGIS Desktop (ArcScan)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wms, vector, vectorization, arcscan

I am facing a problem, when I have a historic map in WMS layer and I need to get buildings from this map (approx. 2000) to vector layer fo further analysis.

Is there any workflow how to automatically vectorize these objects from WMS (for example with ArcScan)?

I don´t want to do it all manually, because it is very time consuming.

Comment: I've used better packages than ArcScan. If you are after polygons use the methods in the answer link by PolyGeo to convert WMS to raster and then raster to polygon http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Raster_to_Polygon/001200000008000000/ (with simplify for nicer looking buildings), if you are after points then convert the centroids to points http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003m000000

Comment: Please note that the above method only works on one band images, if you have RGB input you will need to do some tricky conditional logic between the bands (see Con http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Con/009z00000005000000/) to convert to a single band before converting to polygon. I have used this method to get blue water, black roads and brown buildings from the same colour map.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @MichaelStimson:

> If you are after polygons use the methods in the [answer link by PolyGeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37080) to convert WMS to raster and then raster to polygon
>   http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Raster_to_Polygon/001200000008000000/
>   (with simplify for nicer looking buildings), if you are after points
>   then convert the centroids to points
>   http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003m000000
>
> Please note that the above method only works on one band images, if
>   you have RGB input you will need to do some tricky conditional logic
>   between the bands (see Con
>   http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Con/009z00000005000000/)
>   to convert to a single band before converting to polygon. I have used
>   this method to get blue water, black roads and brown buildings from
>   the same colour map.