# Export WMS-layer to dwg or dxf

Tags: wms, export, autocad

Is it possible to export a WMS-layer to dwg or dxf. I would like to use lines, circles etc. in Autocad, but I can't find out if it is possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by export a WMS layer.  Do you mean request a dwg or dxf format from a WMS service, do you mean convert some output of a WMS request response, or do you mean configure a WMS server to provide those formats

Answer (score 1):

WMS serves images not vectors.  The best option is to contact the source of the service to see if the vectors may be distributed.  Then convert them to dwg or dxf.  Otherwise, you will have to perform a vectorization as this [Q/A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37080/how-to-convert-wms-to-shp) suggests, before conversion.

Comment: It is too much generalized to say that WMS does not serve vectors. It is not at all uncommon to have outputformats like SVG, vector PDF or KML. Of those I believe that KML would be easiest to convert into dxf. However, all WMS servers do not serve KML. Geoservers by default do `http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=459&HEIGHT=346&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml&BBOX=-125.964082115,14.463954423115467,-65.737188885,59.863747576884535&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=`

Answer (score 1):

If you use geoserver +2.5 to store your wms layers you can use this
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/dxf/index.html